# Python Try / Except

Tags: python

What is the correct way to use Try / Except?

I am pretty new to Python and just trying to learn this new technique so any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
temp=input("Please choose an option: ")
try:
    if temp == ("1"):
        fc=input("Fahrenheit: ")
        fer(int(fc))
    if temp == ("2"):
        cf=input("Celsius: ")
        cel(int(cf))
except ValueError:
    print("It looks like you input a value that wasn't a number!")
```

If you put a value in "temp" that isn't 1 or 2 than it should print that it isn't a number but it doesn't, any ideas?

Comment: The [Python page on Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) is probably the best resource for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It looks like you input a value that wasn't a number!" will be printed if there is an exception in your try block. What you wanna do is:

```
temp=input("Please choose an option: ")
try:
    if temp == ("1"):
        fc=input("Fahrenheit: ")
        fer(int(fc))
    elif temp == ("2"):
        cf=input("Celsius: ")
        cel(int(cf))
    else:
        print("It looks like you input a value that wasn't 1 or 2!")
except ValueError:
    print("It looks like you input a value that wasn't a number!")
```

You MUST keep the try and catch because it is possible that the input is not a number.

Comment: I wouldn't say *MUST*. The OP could test `temp.isdigit()`.

Comment: I thought the "Except ValueError:" meant that if theres a value error like if I input "K" instead of 1 or 2 it shows that text but thankyou!

Comment: Well, you *could* raise a ValueError yourself in the else-block, instead of printing the message; in that case the except-clause *would* fire. BUT you should really save exceptions for exceptional circumstances, not for normal flow-control.

Comment: @Edward exception are used for normal flow control, for example to indicate the end of an iterable.

Comment: @tcaswell Fair enough. And manually raising ValueError in the else-clause would prevent duplicating the print-statement. But it still doesn't feel quite right to me...

Answer (score 2):

```
temp=input("Please choose an option: ")
try:
    if temp == ("1"):   # is temp == "1"
        fc=input("Fahrenheit: ") # if yes, get number
        fer(int(fc))  # convert to int, this can raise an exception
    if temp == ("2"):  # is temp == "2"
        cf=input("Celsius: ")  # if yes, get number
        cel(int(cf))  # this can raise an exception
except ValueError:   # capture all ValueError exceptions
    print("It looks like you input a value that wasn't a number!")
```

The value of `temp` can never raise an exception in your code (only the parsing of the input can) so it just passes through.  You need to add a check by hand to make sure `temp` is one of the valid entries.

A better way to do this would be (and you could validate `temp` via an exception):

```
def handle_f():
   fc=input("Fahrenheit: ") # if yes, get number
   fer(int(fc))  # convert to int, this can raise an exception

def handle_C():
    cf=input("Celsius: ")  # if yes, get number
    cel(int(cf))  # this can raise an exception   

fun_dict = {"1": handle_f, "2": handle_c}

try:
   fun_dict[temp]()
except KeyError: # handle temp not being valid
    print('not a valid temperature type')
except ValueError:
    print("It looks like you input a value that wasn't a number!")
```

Comment: Why making it complicated?

Comment: This is more of a code-review point than answering OP's question, but since you opened this can of worms, why not take it a step further and generate the `handle_*` functions from `handlers={'Fahrenheit':fer,'Celsius':cel}`?

Comment: @AliBZ I would argue this is simpler and generic.  Want to also handle `"C"`, `"c"`, and `'celsius'` as valid inputs?  Then all you have to do is add entries to `fun_dict` instead of writing more `elif` blocks.   Same thing if you want to add kelvin.  The logic only needs to be written once.

Comment: What I am trying to say is when the OP has a problem with if and else, there is no need of adding dynamic function calling. I am not saying your answer is bad, Im just saying it is too much for this question.

Comment: @AliBZ On the other hand the OP wanted to handle the validation of `temp` with an exception and this will do that (which is the real reason I thought of doing it this way originally, only started defending it for simplicity reasons after you commented on it)

Comment: @kojiro That is a good idea;)

Comment: @AliBZ, while I agree that your answer is probably more what the original poster was looking for, and probably closer to his level of expertise so far, tcaswell's and kojiro's suggestions made *me* think of the problem in a way that I probably wouldn't have otherwise, and I think that's a good thing. The original poster is free to Accept whichever Answer he prefers, and everyone else is free to upvote or downvote as they feel appropriate. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cleaner to abstract the process of reading an int from the user:

```
def input_int(prompt):
    try:
        return int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        print("It looks like you input a value that wasn't a number!")

temp=input("Please choose an option: ")
if temp == ("1"):
    fc=input_int("Fahrenheit: ")
    fer(fc)
if temp == ("2"):
    cf=input_int("Celsius: ")
    cel(cf)
```